# Where do macros such as global integers get stored in memory?

Tags: c, assembly, system, objdump

I am trying to understand where things are stored in memory such as global and static variables (.data, if not initialized to zero,) etc.

What I am trying to find/considering is a macro such as shown below:

```
#define thisInteger 100
```

Can this be found using objdump?

Additionally, if I were to then assign this to a new variable such as below, where would this be found (guessing in .data):

```
#define THIS_INTEGER 100

int newVariable = THIS_INTEGER;
```

Comment: "Can this be found using objdump". No, macros are preprocessed before even the compilation phase. It's essentially just a "copy and paste" into wherever it is used. The second question depends on where and how that variable is declared - globally? in a function? etc.

Comment: Macros are not stored in memory. All instances where a macro is used is quite literally overwritten by the macro's value during preprocessing.

Comment: The compiler will source the value 100 wherever the macro is used.  It is most likely found in various machine code instructions, using [immediate mode addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Immediate/literal), e.g. when used within expression statements, like `a = a + 100`, or `f(100)`.

Answer (score 5):

Macros are not variables, thus they are not stored anywhere. When you do `#define thisInteger 100`, C preprocessor runs through the source code and replaces `thisInteger` with the integer literal `100`. Asking where `thisInteger` is stored is the same as asking where `100` is stored. To verify this, try something like `&thisInteger`. It won't compile because `&100` is illegal and makes no sense.

> Can this be found using objdump?

No. Preprocessing is a copy-paste processing done before compilation.

> Additionally, if I were to then assign this to a new variable such as below, where would this be found

Depends on where you define the variable.

Answer (score 3):

macros are only compile time (they are preprocessed before compilation)

If you use `gcc` compiler you can see preprocessed C file by using -E gcc option. This preprocessed file will be used in the actual compilation.

[Your preprocessed example](https://godbolt.org/z/sjSZ5P)

1. if the `newVariable` has static or thread storage duration it is initialized to this value before the `main` function is called
2. if the `newVariable` has an automatic storage duration it is initialized to this value when the function is called.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will source the value `100` wherever the macro is used.  It is most likely found in various machine code instructions, using [immediate mode addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Immediate/literal), e.g. when used within expression statements, like `a = a + 100`, or `f(100)`.

The compiler will most likely embed small constants like this on demand within instructions involved in computing expressions like the above, so if we do `a = a + thisInteger;` and `f(thisInteger)`, there will probably be two different machine code instructions that embed the constant `100` as an immediate, one for each such use.  Global data takes work to address, more so than embedding small immediates, so the compiler will not attempt to share the `100` between the two uses as global or static data.

So, yes, you can see the `100` in objdump, but for many usages you probably need to look at the code (`.text`) section to find instructions that use `#100` as an immediate operand (or `#64h` if printed in hex).  In disassembly, you're looking for instructions like `add [rbp+24], #100`, or `move rdi, #100`.

You're right that if you declare a mutable global variable `int x = thisInteger;` you could find the `100` in the data (`.data`) section with `objdump`.  But local variable of the same declaration would be initialized at runtime using machine code instructions, so something like `mov ??, #100`.

Answer (score 1):

try it yourself and see

Starting point:  so.c

```
#define THIS_INTEGER 100

int newVariable = THIS_INTEGER;

void fun0 ( void )
{
    static int hello;
    hello = 100;
}
int fun1 ( void )
{
    int hello;
    hello = 100;
    return(hello);
}
```

the pre-processor does the search and replace for the defines

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -save-temps -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
```

so.i

```
# 1 "so.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "so.c"



int newVariable = 100;

void fun0 ( void )
{
    static int hello;
    hello = 100;
}
int fun1 ( void )
{
    int hello;
    hello = 100;
    return(hello);
}
```

You can see that THIS_INTEGER no longer exists it was just a macro/define its purpose is to keep tract of a constant in this case so that if you want to change it you can change all the relevant instances of it.  But the compiler needs something it can actually compile.

The preprocessor output so.i is then fed to the actual compiler and that produces assembly:  so.s

```
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global fun0
    .arch armv4t
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun0, %function
fun0:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    bx  lr
    .size   fun0, .-fun0
    .align  2
    .global fun1
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun1, %function
fun1:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    mov r0, #100
    bx  lr
    .size   fun1, .-fun1
    .global newVariable
    .data
    .align  2
    .type   newVariable, %object
    .size   newVariable, 4
newVariable:
    .word   100
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
```

That is fed to the assembler and then if you disassemble that you get:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000004 <fun1>:
   4:   e3a00064    mov r0, #100    ; 0x64
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <newVariable>:
   0:   00000064
```

Ehh I had hoped the static would keep it there.  For the global variable being initialized that makes it .data if it werent it would be .bss.  Then in .data you
can see the 100 (0x64).  but it has nothing to do with the macro/define the macro/define simply put the actual value 100 in the actual compiled code.

For the other case, with optimization here, there is no variable on the stack or anything like that the value is placed in the return register, so in this case it lives in a register briefly.

Had the static worked as desired which in hindsight it makes sense it didnt.  I was hoping for what I call a local global.  Its a local variable but adding static puts it in .bss or .data not the stack and then was hoping to see code generated to then put 100 in a variable then put that in that .data/.bss area which works unoptimized of course but that is harder to read:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
   8:   e59f3018    ldr r3, [pc, #24]   ; 28 <fun0+0x28>
   c:   e3a02064    mov r2, #100    ; 0x64
  10:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  14:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  18:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  1c:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  20:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  28:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

0000002c <fun1>:
  2c:   e52db004    push    {r11}       ; (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
  30:   e28db000    add r11, sp, #0
  34:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
  38:   e3a03064    mov r3, #100    ; 0x64
  3c:   e50b3008    str r3, [r11, #-8]
  40:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
  44:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  48:   e28bd000    add sp, r11, #0
  4c:   e49db004    pop {r11}       ; (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
  50:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <newVariable>:
   0:   00000064    andeq   r0, r0, r4, rrx

Disassembly of section .bss:

00000000 <hello.4142>:
   0:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Specifically:

```
   c:   e3a02064    mov r2, #100    ; 0x64
  10:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
```

The 100 is put in a register, then that register value is written to memory where the local global hello from fun0 lives in .bss.

macros/defines simply search and replace, the preprocessor is going to iterate as many times as needed for the various levels/layers of macros until they are all replaced, none of them exist as written in the pre-processed code.  Then that is sent to the compiler.

The VALUE 100 in this case is visible in the final output but it depends on how you used it as to how it is represented or where it is stored.